# ¿Como identificar notificaciones GCM con Enlace y Texto?

Tags: java, android, xml

actualmente  recibo  notificaciones  perfectamente  en mi app, pero deseo saber como identificar  cuando  una notificacion  trae  un enlace  (link) o solo deseo que inicie una Actividad.class

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("link", link);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Como pueden  ver tengo los dos parámetros  para  iniciar  los dos tipos de notificacion  pero la app, solo detecta El Intent  con la Class, aunque  posea  un link en la notificacion.

En Resumen: Como puedo  Colocar  dos Intent para que  detecten  que tipo de notificacion  es.

Actualización: La Solución  1 da el siguiente  Error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La validación se realizaría de esta forma:

```
if(link != null && !link.isEmpty()){
   //Abre url.
   Intent i  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("VARIABLE CON LA URL/")); 
   startActivity(i);
}else{
   //Abre activity mediante PendingIntent
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Amigo muchas  gracias  por su respuesta  , Me ayudó  mucho sólo  que  he pasado un tiempo aplicar  su Validación  pero no logro eliminar  un error que se da al colocarla. Al parecer  una variable  queda  invisible. Soy un poco  novato pero sera que  hay alguna manera  de eliminar  el error de la actualización. gracias

Comment: Bueno también  he probado ingresar  el  ` PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);` dentro del If() pero la Variable  contentIntent queda  en iguales condiciónes. Osea da error

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, aunque puedes crear una sola variable intent, el error es algo básico en desarrollo. Saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias  por responder, bueno  he dejado el resto  del código  para que  lo analize  ya que he probado  la verificacion de liks por medio de su método  pero me da algunos  errores ya que  al ingresar los Intent al metodo If() pierden  su valor, por ejemplo  el metodo **mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent); ** ya no puede  ser invocado  porque  la Variable  **contenInent** queda oculta  por el If(),alguna  otra solución?

Comment: Gracias YA PUDE SOLUCIONAR  EL PROBLEMA, EnCapsule  todo el constructor  en los if() y funcionó  de maravilla. Eres un Master  Hermano  te lo Agradezco  

Comment: Excellente Bryan! me da mucho gusto! Saludos!